# Level 2 I/O in Linux using readdir() possible?

Tags: linux, readdir

I am trying to traverse a directory structure and open every file in that structure.  To traverse, I am using opendir() and readdir().  Since I already have the entity, it seems stupid to build a path and open the file -- that presumably forces Linux to find the directory and file I just traversed.

Level 2 I/O (open, creat, read, write) require a path.  Is there any call to either open a filename inside a directory, or open a file given an inode?

Comment: "that presumably forces Linux to find the directory and file I just traversed." - I'd do some digging/measuring to see if this is worth trying to optimize.  Your presumption here may not be correct.

Comment: If nothing else, it forces ME to build the path when I don't want to!

Comment: There is the (rather new) openat() system call. However there's not much you get from opendir()/readdir() to pass into the openat() call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) to recursively traverse a file tree.

Otherwise, in a portable way, construct your directory + filename path using e.g.

```
snprintf(pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), "%s/%s", dirname, filename);
```

(or perhaps using [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) but don't forget to later `free` the result)

And to answer your question about opening a file in a directory, you could use the *Linux or POSIX2008 specific* [openat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/openat.2.html). But I believe that you should really use `nftw` or construct your path like suggested above. Read also about `O_PATH` and `O_TMPFILE` in [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html).

BTW, the kernel has to access several times the directory (actually, the metadata is cached by file system kernel code), just because *another process* could have written inside it while you are traversing it.

Don't even *think* of opening a file thru its inode number: this will violate several file system abstractions! (but might be hardly possible by insane and disgusting tricks, e.g. `debugfs` - and this could probably harm very strongly your filesystem!!).

Remember that files are generally [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), and can have zero (a process did `open` then [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) a file while keeping the open file descriptor), one (this is the usual case), or several  (e.g. `/foo/bar1` and `/gee/bar2`  could be hard-linked using [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) ....) file names.

Some file systems (e.g. [FAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) ...) don't have real inodes. The kernel fakes something in that case.

Comment: openat is exactly what I was looking for, but why is constantly reconstructing a string path better?

Comment: Because `openat` might not be working or available on every kernel or filesystem. Constructing the string is much faster -so is negligible- than invoking filesystem syscalls (which at least go to the file system cache, and perhaps even to the disk).